# Hopping Count Windows in StreamInsight

Tags: streaminsight

I am developing a StreamInsight application which is supposed to compute a function of every **N** inputs i.e. if N=10 then I want to compute:

```
x_1, x_2, ..., x_10  ---> output_1
x_11, x_12, ..., x_20 ---> output_2
```

etc.

So what I want is a [Hopping Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995783%28v=sql.111%29.aspx), except parameterized on Count rather than Time stamp.

I can't use a [Count Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995695%28v=sql.111%29.aspx) because those produce output every time the count changes.

I am looking for suggestions on how to get around the lack of a **"Hopping Count Window"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using a [User-defined Stream Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290514%28v=sql.111%29.aspx). Events will come into your operator one by one which will make it easy to maintain a collection of the last N events/inputs. Once you've received your Nth event, do the computation, clear your events/inputs collection, and return the result.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing right now. I was hoping there was something built in.