# Modifying event times in StreamInsight

Tags: streaminsight

This is a follow up to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144066/hopping-count-windows-in-streaminsight); the setting is that I am doing time-series prediction using StreamInsight.

Expanding upon the description given there, let me denote by `x_n` my input stream, and for the sake of this example let's suppose that after every 10 observations I predict 10 values ahead; I will call these predictions `p_n`. The series indices will correspond to time, so the first `p_n` will be `p_11`.

So we have

```
x_1, x_2, ..., x_10 --> p_11, p_12, ..., p_20
x_11, x_12, ..., x_20 --> p_21, p_22, ..., p_30
etc.
```

I have a user-defined stream operator which collects the `x_n` from my input stream, and when there are enough events it spits out all the `p_n` for that cycle; TXPower275 confirmed that this is a reasonable strategy.

My next step is to compare the predictions to the actual values as they come in; for this I wanted to [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391157(v=sql.111).aspx) the two streams. Joining works with event timestamps, so I need the timestamps to line up correctly.

*(Aside: although I have point-events, I could just as well use interval-events with short intervals so that I get overlaps for the join...I'll cross that bridge when I get to it).*

*(For completeness: when I receive input events which are in the middle of a cycle, my UDSO outputs a "dummy event" which I identify using a field in the event payload. I filter out the dummy events in order to create the predicted-event-stream.)*

To make this more clear, here is some output from my sink. These are the dummy events alluded to above. The timestamp at the start of each line is the StreamInsight event time (these are point events), and the timestamp at the end of each line is actually a field inside my payload.

```
12:03:30 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:03:30 PM
12:03:40 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:03:40 PM
12:03:50 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:03:50 PM
12:04:00 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:04:00 PM
12:04:10 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:04:10 PM
12:04:20 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:04:20 PM
12:04:30 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:04:30 PM
12:04:40 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:04:40 PM
12:04:50 PM CEP#NO_OUTPUT Predicted NaN  12:04:50 PM
```

The actual predictions look like this:

```
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 0.57 12:05:10 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 0.66 12:05:20 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 1.54 12:05:30 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 1.34 12:05:40 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 1.31 12:05:50 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 0.93 12:06:00 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 2.19 12:06:10 PM
12:05:00 PM CEP#2#Space99 Predicted 0.86 12:06:20 PM
```

Notice that the event time is the same for all of them. This is because my UDSO assigns to ALL the `p_n` (for a cycle) the timestamp of the `x_n` which triggered their computation.

This is consistent with the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290514(v=sql.111).aspx) - *"The timestamp of each output event is based on the timestamp of the corresponding input event"*.

**What I would like to do it create predicted events using the time within the payload fields.**

What I figure I should use is

```
ToPointStreamable(payload => PointEvent<MyPayload>.CreateInsert(payload.eventTime, payload)
```

, and the way I tried to plug this in was like this:

```
var separated_stream = prediction_query.ToEnumerable(StreamEventOrder.FullyOrdered)
                                                   .ToPointStreamable(payload => PointEvent<MyPayload>.CreateInsert(payload.eventTime, payload),
                                                                      AdvanceTimeSettings.IncreasingStartTime);
```

My `prediction_query` is of type `IQStreamable<MyPayload>`.

This isn't working. The events are coming in and the predictions are being generated as shown above, but my "`separated_stream`" might as well not exist.

Printing to the console is done using the same pattern as for my other queries -

```
var observer = cepApplication_.DefineObserver(() => System.Reactive.Observer.Create<T>(/* print action */));
observer.Deploy(name);
separated_stream.Bind(observer).Run()
```

so I don't think there is any error there.

I am using the Event Flow Debugger and cannot find this query... BUT I did find two Processes and I only recognize the flow in one of them so I figure the second one probably has to do with this `separated_stream`. The Diagnostics tell me there are no events in this process or any of its operators. The queries are "Running" as are the operators and nothing in the debugger looks like an error.

Is my definition of the `separated_stream` incorrect, and how should I fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT: The second Process in the Event Flow Debugger is related to the problem query - if I comment out the query then the Process does not show up.

Comment: Update: To get around this I'm going to hold the predictions in the UDSO and emit them one at a time as the corresponding actual values come in - this way the timestamps will be correct. I'd still like to know how to correctly use ToPointStreamable in this setting though

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Not sure I'm quite following everything but some suggestions: 
First, look at subjects. See this blog post: http://www.devbiker.net/post/Using-Subjects-as-a-e2809cFeedback-Loope2809d.aspx. Your details will be slightly different but the concept is the same. 
Second ... a suggestion. Don't look at events in the stream as being points or intervals or edges. They aren't, not really. The event shapes are *expresions* of events in ways that are meaningful and convenient for ingress or egress. *All* events in the engine have start and end times. What you think of as a "point event" simply has an end time that is 1 tick after the start time. Points, intervals and edges are just different expressions of events and ALL events can be points, intervals or edges. Try it in LinqPad and you'll see that you can dump the exact same query all three ways!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have since made enough changes that the context for this question no longer exists (I'm doing the prediction  step outside SI now). I do however plan to re-architect at some point since SI is clearly the correct setting for us to use. When that happens I will look at your subject post again.